# Interpretation of saxon-genitives in various contexts

Tags: meaning-in-context, possessives

For saxon-genitives I am trying to figure out how they interact with articles and what they *can* mean. Consider the following imaginary situations:

1. > Suppose a person & their friend are talking about a book. They mention a book which is available in the website-format as well as in the print-format. They tell their friend that on p. 50 of that book there is a paragraph which they really liked. Their friend borrows the hard copy. Both of them meet again after some time & the friend says, "I read that paragraph, but on the website. The book's page was missing." Here the friend wants to refer to p. 50 of the hard copy as both of them know about the page which is being talked about.

   Does the usage "the book's page" look fair here?
2. > Unlike in the first scenario, where that particular page was known to both the participants, now let's assume that there was no special paragraph & they didn't mention any particular page, but just gave the book to their friend. When both of them met again, the friend said, "I read the book, I specifically loved one paragraph, but I read it online, the book's page was missing". Here they don't know the number of the page being talked about as it was missing at the first place, so in a way they don't know about which page they are talking, but they are sure that *some* page from the book was definitely missing.

   Does the usage "the book's page" look fair here?
3. > A person randomly finds a page in their shelf. It's from someone's diary. They tell this to their roommate (who doesn't maintain a diary, so they are sure that it's not theirs) by saying "I found a diary's page".

   Does the usage "a diary's page" look fair here?

### Note:

There might be constructions which are preferred in these contexts than the ones I am asking, but my question is *not* about them. Speakers might want to be less ambiguous/more clear and hence prefer certain other constructions or some constructions might be more idiomatic than these, but here I am not concerned with those details. My question is only concerned with the constructions I have mentioned and whether they would be accepted or rejected in respective contexts.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes? What have I violated?

Answer (score 2):

In the first two cases, the genitive is wrong, or at least distracting.

"The book's page" means that the book has only one page. In the first case the friend would need to say "page 50 was missing", or perhaps "that page". The reason is "book's" doesn't identify which page you are talking about. In these cases the construction would be rejected.

The third is grammatically correct, but it would be much more natural to say "a page *from* a diary", instead of using a genitive, or using "of". In this case the construction might be accepted, but it would mark the user as a poor English speaker.

Comment: "the genitive is wrong, or at least distracting", but both of these mean two different things. It can be _wrong_ to say "I saw the film" when the listener doesn't at all have any context about the film you watched. We will _have_ to say "I watched _a_ film". When you think it is _wrong_ do you mean something like this? If not, you might be thinking about other prominent readings of the phrase (which I am not denying). I have already said in the question that it can have other readings. It might be ambiguous, distracting, less preferred and what not, but can it **even in one case** be accepted?

Comment: It is wrong. It doesn't express the idea that you want to express.  A native speaker may just ignore the word "book's" and understand you, or they may be distracted by the mistake and confused.  In this forum I assume that learners want to speak English **well** and not just in a way that is marginally acceptable.

Comment: Okay, you say, "The reason is "book's" doesn't identify which page you are talking about". Considering what you say is correct, the expression can agreeably be rejected in case (1), but what about case (2)? If you think "book's" doesn't identify the page, that's what we expect in case (2). So at the moment the reason you have given doesn't seem to be applicable for that case.

Comment: The book's page still implies that the book has a single page, so it isn't a book. Two is wrong.  Why do you **want** this to be correct, even if you know that it isn't good and there are better ways to express yourself?

Comment: I never said I **want** it to be correct, but it seems like you want it to be incorrect. I just said that the reason that you gave doesn't fit for case (2). Also your statements seem to be going orthogonal. You say, "the book's page" means the book only has one page, but then you also say, "book's doesn't identify any page". If the book has only one page, then why is it necessary to identify it? We identify something when we have to choose one instance of it from multiple. Only one of the two reasons you have given can be true.

Comment: I can understand your urge to promote the better version of the construction and in no way I am trying to devalue it, but language learning also comprises of understanding small nuances of meaning with a fine-grained description of what works where and why so. I am just trying to figure out what is making it sound odd/wrong. It can help users understand **why** certain constructions should be avoided. It will only help them IMO.